# Flex 4.6 actionscript 3 executing a SQL alter statment

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

Hello I have a program that is working, I had a customer ask if I could add a notes section to my program, great idea. I added the following code :

```
private var insertStmt:SQLStatement;
private function updateTable():void
        {
            insertStmt = new SQLStatement();
            insertStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
            var sql:String = "";
            sql += "ALTER TABLE Customersold ADD Note TEXT;";
            insertStmt.text = sql;
            insertStmt.execute();
```

that runs fine if the customer is using this version for the first time, but after running it a 2nd time i get an error that the column already exists. How can i fix this?

conn btw is my sql connection.

Edit: This is a program not a mobil app.

Comment: You want to add the same column twice?

Comment: No i want to add it once and make sure it does not attempt to get added again

Comment: I guess what i was trying to find was a way to check if the column existed or not if it didnt add it if it did move on. Not sure if this can be done in actionscript.

Comment: @JoshuaMiller: Have you resolved?

Comment: @JoeTaras Sorry for the delay in responding I did resolve the issue by adding a version to my database and checking the version

Comment: @JoshuaMiller: Don't worry. I'm happy you've resolved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run the statement twice. If you ask SQLLite to add a column that is already there, then throwing an error is the expected behaviour.

If you end up with update scripts in your app like this (which is not uncommon) then the usual way to deal with it is to store a version number in your DB and apply upgrades incrementally as needed. As you haven't done that yet, you can also assume that if no version number was present then it's version 1. Just check this somewhere when your app starts up.

Pseudo code:

```
var version:int = getAppVersionFromDB();
if(version < 2) 
{
    applyV2();
}
if(version < 3) 
{
    applyV3();
}
...  etc ....
```

Then just update functions similar to as you have now.

```
private function applyV2():void
{
    ... some schema changes here ...
   updateSavedVersion(2);
}
```

You get to flesh out the functions yourself.

Comment: How do you set the version?

Comment: Or how do you know what version you should be on?

Comment: Normally you set the version by saving that somewhere in your db too (dedicated version table, settings table, doesn't matter). The version you should be on is the highest possible version that is in your app code.

Comment: Okay in my program I have set the version as 1 and then when the column note gets put into it change the version to 2, now the issue i am having is getting the version from the table

Comment: This worked great I have it set to check for a the version table if == null then it creats the version table adds the starting version. then checks if the version = 1 it runs the code to add the Note to Customersold and adds the fact that now we are on version 2. I can now use this for new updates. Thank you so much! Now all I have left is to look up how to grab send and recieve data from a .php file on my web server.

Answer (score 0):

Your check query change about underline DBMS.

Before your ADD COLUMN statement you must launch this query (different by DBMS):

**SQL SERVER**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM syscolumns c
JOIN sysobjects o
ON c.id = o.id
WHERE o.name = 'Customersold'
AND c.name = 'Note'
```

**ORACLE**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS c
WHERE c.table_name = 'Customersold'
AND c.column_name = 'Note'
```

**MySql**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.table_name = 'Customersold'
AND c.column_name = 'Note'
```

If the result returns a number > 0 so you don't add your column (because exists)

Your method becames:

```
private function updateTable():void
{
    var checkStmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    checkStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
    var sql:String = "ABOVE QUERY";
    checkStmt.text = sql;
    checkStmt.execute();
    checkStmt.getResult(); <-- Here you get the result of your select

    if (CONDITION ABOUT NOT EXISTING FIELD) {
        insertStmt = new SQLStatement();
        insertStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
        sql = "ALTER TABLE Customersold ADD Note TEXT;";
        insertStmt.text = sql;
        insertStmt.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say "ABOVE3 QUERY" that means to insert the 3rd method you listed?

Comment: @JoshuaMiller: Apologize me! Three number is a typing error ;) ABOVE QUERY (in base of your DBMS)

Comment: I am not able to test yet, I am working for another 3 hours. I will test when I get home thank you!

Comment: @JoshuaMiller: Hi, don't worry ;) I'm very curios :D :D

Comment: Just to make sure i understand that first var sql:String = "ABOVE QUERY"; would be one of the 3 things. How do I know what version of SQL AIR makes? the program creates the DB for me

Comment: @JoshuaMiller: Hi, do you use a SQL local DB on Flex or you use a normal DB access?

Comment: just to add to this, If your using the `SQLConnection` class, you can call `conn.loadSchema(); var schema:SQLSchemaResult =conn.getSchemaResult()` to fetch the DB schema

Comment: Probably worth noting that although this method will work, it becomes increasingly complicated as more changes happen over time. The OP is just adding a column, but if adding new tables, indexes, changing keys, dropping some columns etc then this is complex. You end up effectively writing your own schema merging system which is non trivial.